# Appium Android click checkbox

Tags: android, appium

I am creating automated tests using appium to test an android app. The issue that I am facing right now, is that I cannot select a checkbox, because the checkbox contains linked text.

I am using the following code to get checkbox element and click it -

```
WebElement termsAndConditionsCheckbox = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(baseTest.getAndroidElementId("checkbox_terms_and_conditions"))));
termsAndConditionsCheckbox.click();
```

In app code, the checkbox's text is set as follows -

```
mCheckboxTermsAndConditions.setText(Html.fromHtml(mSignUpAcceptTermsAndConditions));
mCheckboxTermsAndConditions.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

From debugging options on android device, I turned on the options to see pointer location of click event, and I see the appium clicks at the center of the checkbox (box + text), and unfortunately, that point contains a linked text, so the webview is launched, as opposed to "checking" the checkbox

I do not see a custom click() in appium, which would allow me to check the checkbox.

Would appreciate any ideas / help.

Comment: Hi use uiautomatorviewer to find the checkbox only not text and please share the screenshot of uiautomatorviewer so that we can understand better

Answer (score 2):

You can use find element `By.className` instead of `By.id`.

So for multiple such elements you can have them referenced with index (in this case 0), for example.

```
WebElement submit = (WebElement) driver.findElements(By.className(RADIO_BUTTON)).get(0);
submit.click();
```

Hoping this helps.

Comment: I can find it and getAttributes but click is never performed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Instead of clicking on the checkbox directly..first get the location of checkbox and adjust the location by adding / subtracting some pixels so that it will always click on the exactly on the checkbox and not in the centre of the whole checkbox element.

You can use below code snippet :

```
    WebElement element =driver.findelement(By.xpath("YourXpath"));
        Point p=element.getLocation();
        driver.tap(1, p.getX()+10, p.getY()+10, 1);
```

Comment: Ok, I did manage to get this approach working after some trial and error, using getX()+5 and getY()+5. I think if possible however, it would be better to have whoever wrote the UI put the link and text in a separate view.  I've found in the past that there are other selection issues associated with linkifying text in the same view as a checkbox.